# Transfer bitcoin from gdax to my nano s and now it’s pending

Tags: transactions

I transferred 1.05 bitcoin using gdax to my nano s
and now it is pending in my Coinbase account without
any miners fee or transaction ID. I was never given a
chance to review the transaction! The receiving 
address is correct. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted from GDAX](https://support.gdax.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2430150-how-to-deposit-and-withdraw-digital-currencies#times):

> Withdrawal transactions will be generated instantly, and the value
>   withdrawn from your account.
>
> **There are occasional delays with both deposit and withdrawal**
>   **transactions**. If you believe that your transactions are taking too
>   long, please contact us and provide as much of the following
>   transaction information as possible: